# having trouble getting data from puppeteer .innertext js

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, innertext

im having trouble getting the text that is listed in the element. I thought I did it right but i keep getting errors. This is the Element im trying to get. Any help would be great. Cant link the site because you have to login to get to this page.

```
<p><span class="query-player_current">1</span>
/
<span class="query-player_max">32</span></p>
```

(Trying to get the "1" and "32")^

and this is the code that i have.

```
const result = await page.evaluate (() => {
        let playerCount = document.querySelector('query-player_current').innerText;
        let playerCountMax = document.querySelector('query-player_max').innerText;
        return {
            playerCount,
            playerCountMax
        }
    })
```

this is the errors im getting

````
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:73
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:48:12)
    at async downloadLog (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\commands\test2.js:56:20)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\commands\test2.js:15:3)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:112:20)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.evaluate (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:860:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at downloadLog (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\commands\test2.js:56:31)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\commands\test2.js:15:3)```
````

Comment: Can you try adding some waitForSelector?

Comment: Since you're using class to query you need to add a dot like `document.querySelector('.query-player_current')`

Comment: You forgot to add `.` before the selector name in querySelector and that's why it's returning null.

Comment: hmm alright. now i cant console log it? i tried console.log(value) but didnt work. saying value is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use '.' as prefix, If you are using classnames in query.
try

```
 document.querySelector('.query-player_current')
 document.querySelector('.query-player_max')
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)